# How to solve redirect_uri_mismatch error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, google-plus

Actually i am trying to make Google+ sign in using ROR. When i clicked on sign in link,i got the below error.

```
400. That’s an error.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
```

I am providing my code snippets in below sections

```
views\layouts\application.html.erb

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Google</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <% if current_user %>
      Signed in as <strong><%= current_user.name %></strong>!
      <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, id: "sign_out" %>
  <% else %>
      <%= link_to "Sign in with Google", "/auth/google_oauth2", id: "sign_in" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div>
  <%= yield %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

controllers\application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_user

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

controllers\sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

config\routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'

  resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resource :home, only: [:show]

  root to: "home#show"
end
```

config\initializers\omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, '641362005580-inubab5v5p5bv0596dfd9c5bh9s0kr87.apps.googleusercontent.com', 'auDnCkSEelcW6Cs7-YE7VqLR', {client_options: {ssl: {ca_file: Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s}}}
end
```

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

In google developer's console screen my REDIRECT URIS and javascript origin are

```
REDIRECT URIS:http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback
 JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS :http://localhost:3000
```

I am using rails version-4.0.2 and ruby version-1.9.3.Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have your redirect uri wrong in your Google developer console.

You probably want: http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback.

If you want to follow a tutorial that covers this OAuth flow with Google, [check out this one by my colleague Greg Baugues on the Twilio blog](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/09/gmail-api-oauth-rails.html).